# Circular dependency, fine or bad?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm making some sort of personal framework, for educational and practical purposes, and encountered a design problem i'd like to share.

I have a `Component` namespace, that contains various classes for, um, components (i. e. bits of reusable ViewModels). One of them is `Component\Form`, a generator class for building form templates from models. After some time i realized a need for some `Validation` service classes, that will perform non-model specific validations, like checking captcha.

The problem is, my default form validation accumulates error messages and displays them in one place. So, to accomplish this, my `Validator` classes need to have access to the `Form`, and `Form` class adds `Validator` classes via setter injection.

So, this creates circular dependency. From one side, there's an (although optional) dependency of `Form` on `Validator` classes, and from other side, i have to inject a `Form` class into every `Validator` i add. I wonder, if this approach is fine from the point of OOP design, and if not, what problems could possibly arise from that, and how could i possibly resolve it.

I'm sorry i don't provide any relevant code, i think it would take too much space to be readable, but if necessary, i'll gladly post anything to clarify specific moments of the problem.

Comment: Post at least interfaces of your validators. It's a bit complex to rely on assumptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the validator should not have a dependency on the form, because it should not display an error. The form can ask the validator to check some raw input against some rule. If the validation fails, the validator might return an error code or message, based on which the form can display an error. Displaying that error is not the job of the validator.

Comment: Right now my validators are checking against some rules, and adds messages to the form. It doesn't outright display anything.

Comment: Right, but they shouldn't add the messages to the form. The form could get the message from the validator. It could also be the other way around, where a controller would command the validator to validate the form and add messages. Either way, one of them is the initiator, and the other one doesn't need to have a dependency to the initiator. I would choose to keep the validator independent, so you might also use it to validate input from files, urls, other kinds of non-form post data, or databases. Validation shouldn't be strictly tied to a form, I think.

Comment: Well, actually, there are two kinds of validators in my framework. Ones i told about, and other are `ModelValidator`, that are part of a `Model` class, which contain general `Model` validation logic, like checking that not-nullable fields are not empty, emails and phones are properly formatted, and these indeed work everywhere.

Comment: Model is not a class, and should never be. Why? Well, because you end up with broken SoC and SRP.

Comment: Well, we're getting a bit into details, which is hard, because I cannot see your code and everyone's approach is a bit different, but I would think one kind of validator should be enough and they should operator on a very abstract level. And then, maybe, you could create a FormValidator that validates a form using other validators. That class will have knowledge of both Form and the actual Validator and it separates those two. That way, neither form, not validator need to know about each other.

Answer (score 0):

i would say that you miss some kind of mvc. i would keep that the validator depends on form as it have to access all data and passing raw values will be tedious and complex (comparing two passwords, captcha, checking if one field is longer that 5 only if another is shorter than 3). but i would not make that a form depends on a validator. because form doesn't know if it requires a validation. sometimes you need to trigger validators A and B and sometimes B and C. and form doesn't have the knowledge to make that decision. that's the controller's job. i would add some kind of ValidationGroup / ValidatorHandler etc. which references a form and (a group of) validators. then a controller would trigger the correct group of validators

Comment: Actually, i do use MVC pattern, and actual injection of `Validators` to `Form` are done inside controller via setters.